# Randomly select a UIImage

Tags: ios, uiimage, swift

I need to pick one of these `dots`. I add them all before `viewDidLoad`, I need it to pick a random one. My current code returns the error `cannot assign to 'openingScreenDynamicDot in 'self'`. How is this fixed?

**CODE:**

```
    let openingScreenDynamicDot = UIImage()
    let dotOne = UIImage(named: "dot1.png")
    let dotTwo = UIImage(named: "dot2.png")
    let dotThree = UIImage(named: "dot3.png")
    let dotFour = UIImage(named: "dot4.png")
    let dotFive = UIImage(named: "dot5.png")
    let dotSix = UIImage(named: "dot6.png")
    let dotSeven = UIImage(named: "dot7.png")
    let dotEight = UIImage(named: "dot8.png")
    let dotNine = UIImage(named: "dot9.png")
    let dotTen = UIImage(named: "dot10.png")
    let dotEleven = UIImage(named: "dot11.png")
    let dotTwelve = UIImage(named: "dot12.png")
    let dotThirteen = UIImage(named: "dot13.png")
    var imageNumber = arc4random()%13

override func viewDidLoad() {
        let theRandomImages = [dotOne, dotTwo, dotThree, dotFour, dotFive, dotSix, dotSeven, dotEight, dotNine, dotTen, dotEleven, dotTwelve, dotThirteen]
        openingScreenDynamicDot = theRandomImages.objectAtIndex(imageNumber)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declare constants with the let keyword and variables with the var keyword.

So change let openingScreenDynamicDot to var openingScreenDynamicDot

also, a swift native array does not have a objectAtIndex method so..

change

openingScreenDynamicDot = theRandomImages.objectAtIndex(imageNumber)

to

openingScreenDynamicDot = theRandomImages[imageNumber]

Comment: I now get the error `Array<UIImage> does not have a member named 'objectAtIndex'`

Comment: use theRandomImages[imageNumber] instead

Comment: objectAtIndex is for NSArray, not for a swift native array.

Comment: I get `Could not find an overload for 'subscipt' that accepts the supplied arguments.`

Comment: you also need to add : UIImage[] in front of theRandomImages so swift knows its an array of uIImage

Comment: It gives me `Expected member name or constructor call after type name` with the line `let theRandomImages = UIImage[dotOne, dotTwo, dotThree, dotFour, dotFive, dotSix, dotSeven, dotEight, dotNine, dotTen, dotEleven, dotTwelve, dotThirteen]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55610/discussion-between-benr783-and-david-xu).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code to generate one of your random "dots".

```
override func viewDidLoad(){
let openingScreenDynamicDot.image = UIImage(named: "dot\(arc4random_uniform(13) + 1).png")
}
```

This is called "String Interpolation". For more info, [Click here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html/here).

I hope this can help you if you are still having problems.